# lxml How do I preserve the HTML tag structure?

Tags: python, html, xml

I have a url address: https://www.nepalitimes.com/here-now/a-short-walk-up-the-panjshir/

I want to use LXML to extract the body content of the news page, so I use xpath: //article, but it gets beyond the body tag

Since LXML changes the HTML page structure during initialization, can anyone tell me how to solve this problem?

```
import requests
from lxml import etree
res = requests.get('https://www.nepalitimes.com/here-now/a-short-walk-up-the-panjshir/')
html = etree.HTML(res.text)
print(''.join(html.xpath('//article')[1]))
```

I wanted to end at The end of The text, but The print contained The extension to The bottom: "The Himalayan Odyssey September 12, 2020 Photos: MOUNTAIN TRAVEL NEPAL Ieutenant Colonel J O M Roberts..."

I think the reason is this:

```
html = etree.HTML(res.text)
print(etree.tostring(html) == res.text)  # False
```

After etree.html (), the order of the HTML nodes has changed, but I don't know how to keep the order of the nodes unchanged

Comment: Can you please share the expected output?

Comment: 'Kids playing on rusted tanks abandoned by the retreating Russians,.................... They are the lucky ones, so many left behind to face a frighteningly unreliable future.'

This is my expected output,
Because the article is too long... In front of the beginning of the article... This is followed by the end of the article

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if perfectly understood but you could just do string manipulation:

```
import requests
res = requests.get("https://www.nepalitimes.com/here-now/a-short-walk-up-the-panjshir/")

body = '<body' + res.text.split("<body")[1].replace("</html>", "")
```

This basically pulles out the entire body tag

Comment: Thank you, it does not solve my problem, after etree.html (body), the node order is still changed